# Replacement for removed HibernateDaoSupport.getSession() method in Spring 5.3 available?

Tags: spring, spring-data

In Spring 4.3, the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()` method allowed us to obtain a wrapped session that was managed by Spring. That means, we did not have to close the session at the end of the unit of work.

Unfortunately, in Spring 5.3 this method was removed. I could not find it's equivalent in `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport`. Did I miss something?

We are currently upgrading from Spring 4.3 to 5.3 and we do not want to use Spring's transactionManager that would come with `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`, because we would have to annotate every DAO + method call with @Repository and @Transactional and there are many places where that could break our application. Instead, we would like to replace our legacy calls for `HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()` with a Spring 5.3 equivalent. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, I have found an appropriate solution.

This code:

```
public List<?> executeDBQuery(final String queryString) {
   final Query query =  this.getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);   
   return query.list();
}
```

can be replaced by

```
public List<?> executeDBQuery(final String queryString) {
   return (List) hibernateTemplate.execute((HibernateCallback) session -> session.createSQLQuery(queryString).list();
}
```

Using the `HibernateTemplate.execute()` wrapper-method, since `.execute` opens/closes the session, which is exactly what I was looking for.